# Converting IEnumerable<string> to Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, casting, ienumerable, deferred-execution

after adding `bool distinct` to method Splitter and checking if `distinct is true` the code broke. The quesry now instead of being dictionary is `IEnumerable<string>`, but whould be `Dictionary<string, int>`. How could it be solved?

This is the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

And the code:

```
private Dictionary<string, int> Splitter(string[] file, bool distinct)
{
    var query = file
        .SelectMany(i => File.ReadLines(i)
        .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(word => word.ToLower())
        .Where(word => !StopWords.Contains(word))
        .Where(word => !StopWordsPl.Contains(word))
        .Where(word => !PopulatNetworkWords.Contains(word))
        .Where(word => !word.All(char.IsDigit)));
        if (distinct)
        {
        query = query.Distinct();
        }

       query.GroupBy(word => word)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
       return query;
}
```

Comment: GroupBy and ToDictionary do not modify underlying object, you do it correctly few lines above query = query.Distinct();

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ToDictionary` returns what you need. Just return that instead of returning `query`.

```
return query.GroupBy(word => word)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i know!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the `distinct` code now only has the effect of making the count value here always `1`. I find it unlikely that this was intended, and don't see any use for `distinct`.

Comment: @Ken'ichiMatsuyama here's a more efficient way to do it, then: `.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => distinct ? 1 : g.Count());`. Actually calling `Distinct` is unnecessary work for both the computer and the human code-reader.